# Laravel: use extended controller or Traits or something else?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

To maintain my Laravel application and save myself from a lot of duplicate code I have made the following solution:

**BaseController**

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{ 
    public function get($id){
        return $this->baseService->get($id);
    }

    public function getAll(){
        return $this->baseService->getAll();
    }
}
```

**BaseService**

```
class BaseService
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function get($id){
        return response()->json($this->model->where('id', $id)->first());
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->model->get();
    } 
}
```

**MyController**

```
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    protected $model;
    protected $baseService;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model= new Model();
        $this->baseService = new BaseService($this->model);
    }

    /**
     * This controller has all the functionality from BaseController now
     */
}
```

What I'm wondering if this is a good method. Should I stick with this or should I use a different approach? I've heard about Traits but not sure if they are doing the same thing. It's Laravel 5.5 I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, traits are used to move methods out of a controller regularly.  A good example that the Laravel framework uses is the `ThrottlesLogin` trait.  Take a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php#L20 
to see how the methods are moved outside of a controller but can be still accessed by importing the trait using the `use` keyword.

While traits would work for your use case I wouldn't use them here for the functionality you are looking for. I would use the **repository pattern**.  It would better separate your code and make it more reusable.

Take a look at https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ for more information on the repository pattern.  Basically, you would separate your code into a separate repository and use Laravel's built in IoC to inject the repository into your controller.

**MyController**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
   protected $repo; 

   public function __construct(MyRepository $myRepository)
   {
     $this->repo = $myRepository;
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $myStuff = $this->repo->all();
   }

   // you can also inject the repository directly in the controller
   // actions.
   // look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers
   public function other(MyRepository $repo)
   {
       $myStuff = $repo->all();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is really useful material. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect use case for a Trait. Traits are intended for reusable functions. They're super simple to implement, and won't take more than a few minutes to change what you have.

Here is a great article on them: https://www.conetix.com.au/blog/simple-guide-using-traits-laravel-5

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and info. As @WarrenR suggested would you chose the repository pattern over traits in this usecase?

Comment: If the only thing you would use this trait for is database interaction, then yes you could go with a repository pattern. The only thing I would suggest is asking yourself if it's worth it. A trait (in my opinion) is much simpler to implement, and it's easy to figure out what everything does in three months when you come back and forget what everything means.